# Spring Redis Connection(via XML settings) using Lettuce as client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, lettuce

I am trying to connect redis via my spring mvc application for session storage. I am using Lettuce as redis client. While doing so, I encounter an error stating..

**NoClassDefFoundError: com/lamdaworks/redis/protocol/CommandEncoder
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationSessionRepository.java:788)**

Same works fine when I use **jedis client** api.

Note : I am not using any build tool like maven. I have downloaded independent jars. Following is the list and versions

**lettuce-3.5.0.Final.jar**  (Also all supporting jars as mentioned in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/biz.paluch.redis/lettuce/3.5.0.Final)

**Spring-data-redis-1.7.1.release.jar**

My app-config.xml is as followed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory" p:hostName="127.0.0.1" p:port="6379" p:password="password"/>   
   </beans>
```

web.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring Session with Servlet</display-name> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
     <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please assist with any possible mis-configurations or errors.

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like a version incompatibility. Have you tried using lettuce 3.4.2.Final? You might also want to upgrade Spring Data Redis to 1.7.8.RELEASE and Spring Session 1.3.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Hi, I used all the mentioned version. Still I am facing the same issue. Is the re any other way to create connection via xml setting. I am facing error at save delta for principal_name_index_name

Comment: Please approach the dependency issue using Maven to pull in all required dependencies. Maven also takes care of Guava, Netty and Commons Pooling2 (see http://redis.paluch.biz/dependencies.html for lettuce 4, you'd need to inspect the pom.xml file of lettuce 3.4 for further dependencies).